# I have two modules in a directory, one will import the other won't. No module named

Tags: python, import

I have two modules, say a.py and b.py, in the same subfolder. The tree is:
top-
tools-
a.py
b.py

From top, I can import a.py, but b.py gives a "No module named b" error.

I can import "tools.b", and I can import "top.tools", but I cannot import "top.tools.b". Import "top.tools.a" works fine. I have empty **init**.py files in all directories, and the import worked fine before I let the project sit for a month or so. It is on my local hard drive and no changes have been made (Yeah, this happens.)

For reasons I have no control over, this is in Python 2.7 and upgrading at this time is not an option. The OS is Windows 10 and it is current.

I have worked with sys.path to make sure the directories are found. I have checked that the file exists and that it is a file with the os tools. I have restarted the PC. I tried debugging with PyCharm, VSCode, and the command window. I get the same error in all tools.

Comment: Where are you importing from? The command line, or some script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem. It was related to the same situation that prevents me from upgrading, namely, some other file setting the file paths in a non-obvious way. The top level project has some hidden functionality.